# Stanford NLP - Phrasal Installation

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 machine and try to install Stanford Phrasal. I couldn't install it from source, it gives error as :

> *$ gradle installDist*
>
> FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'installDist' not found in root project 'phrasal-master'.
> - Try: Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 7.359 secs

I have followed steps in

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/phrasal  , 
http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/wiki/Software/Phrasal#Installation
links. To be more specific :

- export CORENLP_HOME=
- export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

I have all the dependencies installed. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the directory to phrasal folder you have downloaded. You can use

```
cd path/to/your/phrasal/directory
```

Then you can try this to see available gradle tasks

```
gradle tasks
```

There must be installDist task in the list. If not you are in a wrong directory.
If you installDist command is there you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to go to phrasal directory to run that command.
I remember it was in:

```
cd path/phrasal-master/
```

You will need to be in that directory where is the script `build.gradle`